# Topology on a totally ordered set without a least and greatest element.

Tags: general-topology

Can anyone help me solve this?

Assume that the totally ordered set ≤ do not have a least and greatest element. And that we define the open interval in x as

(a, b) = {x ∈ X : a < x < b} when a

We call a subset O ⊆ X open if there is for every x ∈ O is an open interval (a,b) such that x ∈ (a,b) ⊆ O. Show that the family of all open sets is a topology on X. (Ø is considered open as it does not contain any x)

Answer (score 1):

Just check the axioms of a topology. For an union of open sets take some $x$ of the union, than there is an index such that there is some interval, just check that the interval is contained in the union too.
For a finite intersection there must be finite many $a_i$ and $b_i$ such that your $x\in(a_i,b_i)$ for all $i$. Now take the biggest $a_i$ and the smallest $b_i$.